# User Input to Bash Alias?

Tags: git, bash, alias

Whenever I'm using git, I generally add, commit, and push at the same time. So I created an alias in bash to make it simpler:

```
alias acp='git add -A;git commit -m "made changes";git push'
```

How do I make it so that the I can change the commit message from "made changes" to something else while I'm running the *acp* command? For example:

```
acp "added the Timer Class"
```

The above I would want to run everything that the *acp* command does and make "added the timer class" the commit message. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An alias cannot accept parameters, so you need to create a function:

```
acp ()
{
        git add -A;git commit -m "$1";git push
}
```

as always, store it in `~/.bashrc` and source it with `source ~/.bashrc`.

Or better ([good hint, binfalse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359049/user-input-to-bash-alias/19359080?noredirect=1#comment28683956_19359080)) to avoid performing a command if the previous was not successful, add `&&` in between them:

```
acp ()
{
        git add -A && git commit -m "$1" && git push
}
```

Execute it with

```
acp "your comment"
```

It is important that you use double quotes, otherwise it will just get the 1st parameter.

Comment: I'd also recommend to substitute the `;` by `&&`. Thus, if one of the tasks fails subsequent tasks aren't executed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This will really speed up my workflow. Thanks to _binfalse_ as well.